# How to rename files in all directories to the same name on terminal

Tags: bash

I have 31 directories from sample1 to sample31 with similar naming files.

```
❯ find . -maxdepth 2 -type f
./sample5/palette-david-clode-2B4dYFgYAyQ-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg
./sample5/david-clode-2B4dYFgYAyQ-unsplash.jpg
./sample5/david-clode-2B4dYFgYAyQ-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg
./sample2/amy-syiek-0n9lbdiAKi0-unsplash.jpg
./sample2/amy-syiek-0n9lbdiAKi0-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg
./sample2/palette-amy-syiek-0n9lbdiAKi0-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg
./sample3/marc-meyer-9JE6BLqMYYM-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg
./sample3/palette-marc-meyer-9JE6BLqMYYM-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg
./sample3/marc-meyer-9JE6BLqMYYM-unsplash.jpg
...more files
```

Now I'd like to

- change all files starting with `palette-` to `palette.jpg`.
  Foe example:
  `./sample5/palette-david-clode-2B4dYFgYAyQ-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg` to `./sample5/palette.jpg`.
- change all files ending with  `.thumbnail.jpg` to `sample.jpg`.
  For example:
  `./sample5/david-clode-2B4dYFgYAyQ-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg` to `./sample5/sample.jpg`.

How can I do this on the terminal?

I tried this but didn't work:

```
for dir in */; do; for file in "palette-*.jpg"; do mv "$file" "palette.jpg"; done;for file in "*.thumbnail.jpg"; do mv "$file" "sample.jpg";done;done
```

Result:

```
mv: rename palette-*.jpg to palette.jpg: No such file or directory
mv: rename *.thumbnail.jpg to sample.jpg: No such file or directory
mv: rename palette-*.jpg to palette.jpg: No such file or directory
mv: rename *.thumbnail.jpg to sample.jpg: No such file or directory
mv: rename palette-*.jpg to palette.jpg: No such file or directory
...
```

Comment: Wouldn't `palette-david-clode-2B4dYFgYAyQ-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg` have been renamed into `sample.jpg` according to the first rule - so the 2:nd rule wouldn't get the chance to rename it into `palette.jpg`?

Comment: These are two different files. The file names with `palette-` move to `palette.jpg`. So move them first then move `*.thumbnail.jpg` to `sample.jpg`?

Comment: Ok, so you mean to reverse `1` and `2`? Do `2` first, then `1`?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expanded wildcard includes the directory name. To rename a file but keep it in the same directory, keep the directory name.  Your current attempt would replace the *directory and* the name with just a file name, effectively moving all files to the current directory.

```sh
for dir in */; do
    for file in "$dir"/palette-*.jpg; do
        mv "$file" "$dir/palette.jpg"
    done
    for file in "$dir"/*.thumbnail.jpg; do
        mv "$file" "$dir/sample.jpg"
    done
done
```

Notice also how the wildcards need to be outside the quotes.

Obviously, if any of the wildcards match more than one file, the last `mv` in the loop will overwrite all the previous ones in that directory.

Comment: One liner: `❯ for dir in */; do for file in "$dir"/palette-*.jpg; do mv "$file" "$dir/palette.jpg"; done; for file in "$dir"/*.thumbnail.jpg; do mv "$file" "$dir/sample.jpg" ; done; done`

Comment: That seems like a bad idea, but you can replace each newline except the ones after `do` with a semicolon, like you already had in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

You could still use the initial `find` but add `-name` to filter out the files you'd like to rename:

```
#!/bin/bash

# rule 2
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' path
do
    dir="$(dirname "$path")"
    echo mv "$path" "$dir/palette.jpg"
    mv "$path" "$dir/palette.jpg"
done < <(find sample* -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'palette*.jpg' -print0)

# rule 1
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' path
do
    dir="$(dirname "$path")"
    echo mv "$path" "$dir/sample.jpg"
    mv "$path" "$dir/sample.jpg"
done < <(find sample* -maxdepth 2 -type f -name '*.thumbnail.jpg' -print0)
```

Output (for the sample files you've provided):

```
mv sample2/palette-amy-syiek-0n9lbdiAKi0-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg sample2/palette.jpg
mv sample3/palette-marc-meyer-9JE6BLqMYYM-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg sample3/palette.jpg
mv sample5/palette-david-clode-2B4dYFgYAyQ-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg sample5/palette.jpg
mv sample2/amy-syiek-0n9lbdiAKi0-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg sample2/sample.jpg
mv sample3/marc-meyer-9JE6BLqMYYM-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg sample3/sample.jpg
mv sample5/david-clode-2B4dYFgYAyQ-unsplash.thumbnail.jpg sample5/sample.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If using GNU find, you can use the `-execdir` option:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "palette-*.jpg" -execdir mv \{\} palette.jpg \;
```

This will run the `mv` with its current working directory set to the one each file is in, so you don't have to worry about adding it to the destination file path.

Comment: `{}` need not be escaped, it doesn't expand to anything in bash. And without `-mindepth 2` this will rename files in the current directory as well.

Comment: @oguzismail The find man page says to escape `{}`, so I always do.

Comment: It says *might need to be escaped*, but not a bad habit anyway